# Algebraic means for finding the range for $\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm reading about how to find the range for a $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ function, but the algebraic method isn't very clear. Say, for example, we want to calculate the range for:

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{(x-4)(x+2)}
$$

The supplied method is this:

> Let $y = \frac{1}{(x-4)(x+2)} \space\space\space \therefore y = \frac{1}{x^2 - 2x - 8} \space\space\space\space\space\space...[1]$
>
> From $[1]$ $yx^2 - 2xy - 8y = 1$
>
> i.e. $yx^2 - 2xy - 8y - 1 = 0$
>
> For $y \not= 0$ this is a quadratic in x.
>
> Thus, for real x, $\space4y^2 - 4(y)(-8y - 1) \ge0$
>
> i.e. $y(9y + 1) \ge 0$

But I don't understand the jump from $yx^2 - 2xy - 8y - 1 = 0$ to $\space4y^2 - 4(y)(-8y - 1) \ge0$.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a quadratic in $x$, whose domain is the set of reals. Hence, we need for the discriminant of the quadratic equation to be greater than or equal to zero (else $x \in \mathbb C)$. That is, we need:

$(b^2 - 4ac = \space4y^2 - 4(y)(-8y - 1)\geq 0)$